# AWS lambda stuck importing library

Tags: python, docker, aws-lambda, amazon-ecr

I am trying to deploy my ECR image to aws lambda. The image works fine locally, but on aws, it gets stuck importing this library https://github.com/jianfch/stable-ts.

```
import json
import boto3
import requests
import numpy
print("All imports ok 1 ...")

from stable_whisper import load_model
print("All imports ok 2 ...")
```

The first statement is printed but it gets stuck on importing and the second statement never got printed until it timed out.

Docker File:

```
# Build FFmpeg
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8 as lambda-base

COPY requirements.txt ./
COPY myfunction.py ./

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

WORKDIR /ffmpeg_sources
RUN yum install autoconf automake bzip2 bzip2-devel cmake libxcb libxcb-devel \
    freetype-devel gcc gcc-c++ git libtool make pkgconfig zlib-devel -y -q

# Compile NASM assembler
RUN curl -OL https://www.nasm.us/pub/nasm/releasebuilds/2.15.05/nasm-2.15.05.tar.bz2
RUN tar xjvf nasm-2.15.05.tar.bz2
RUN cd nasm-2.15.05 && sh autogen.sh && \
    ./configure --prefix="/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg_build" \
    --bindir="/ffmpeg_sources/bin" && \
    make && make install

# Compile Yasm assembler
RUN curl -OL https://www.tortall.net/projects/yasm/releases/yasm-1.3.0.tar.gz
RUN tar xzvf yasm-1.3.0.tar.gz
RUN cd yasm-1.3.0 && \
    ./configure --prefix="/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg_build" \
    --bindir="/ffmpeg_sources/bin" && \
    make && make install

# Compile FFmpeg
RUN curl -OL https://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2
RUN tar xjvf ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2
RUN cd ffmpeg && \
    export PATH="/ffmpeg_sources/bin:$PATH" && \
    export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg_build/lib/pkgconfig" && \
    ./configure \
    --prefix="/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg_build" \
    --pkg-config-flags="--static" \
    --extra-cflags="-I/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg_build/include" \
    --extra-ldflags="-L/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg_build/lib" \
    --extra-libs=-lpthread \
    --extra-libs=-lm \
    --enable-libxcb \
    --bindir="/ffmpeg_sources/bin" && \
    make && \
    make install
# Final image with code and dependencies
FROM lambda-base

COPY myfunction.py /var/task/


CMD ["myfunction.lambda_handler"]
```

inside the requirements.txt, I tried both stable-ts and git+https://github.com/jianfch/stable-ts.git

I appreciate any help.

Comment: How do you install `stable_whisper`? Might be helpful to see some of the Dockerfile snippets, including parent image and installation of dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

`stable_whisper` has a lot of dependencies and some of them contain compiled code (`ffmpeg`).
Python packages that contain compiled code [aren't always compatible with Lambda runtimes](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-python-package-compatible/) by default. I don’t know how to build `ffmpeg`, but I can point you to a useful [AWS sample](https://github.com/aws-samples/serverless-ui-testing-using-selenium/blob/48373bfadbe0514d4d2ce6e17667e572adf2f02f/Dockerfile), which utilizes python packages based on this dependency. Maybe it will contribute to solving your problem or maybe others will be able to help you further.

**Sample Dockerfile:**

```
# Install dependencies
…

# Build FFmpeg
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8 as ffmpeg
WORKDIR /ffmpeg_sources
RUN yum install autoconf automake bzip2 bzip2-devel cmake libxcb libxcb-devel \
    freetype-devel gcc gcc-c++ git libtool make pkgconfig zlib-devel -y -q

# Compile NASM assembler
RUN curl -OL https://www.nasm.us/pub/nasm/releasebuilds/2.15.05/nasm-2.15.05.tar.bz2
RUN tar xjvf nasm-2.15.05.tar.bz2
RUN cd nasm-2.15.05 && sh autogen.sh && \
    ./configure --prefix="/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg_build" \
    --bindir="/ffmpeg_sources/bin" && \
    make && make install

# Compile Yasm assembler
RUN curl -OL https://www.tortall.net/projects/yasm/releases/yasm-1.3.0.tar.gz
RUN tar xzvf yasm-1.3.0.tar.gz
RUN cd yasm-1.3.0 && \
    ./configure --prefix="/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg_build" \
    --bindir="/ffmpeg_sources/bin" && \
    make && make install

# Compile FFmpeg
RUN curl -OL https://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2
RUN tar xjvf ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2
RUN cd ffmpeg && \
    export PATH="/ffmpeg_sources/bin:$PATH" && \
    export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg_build/lib/pkgconfig" && \
    ./configure \
    --prefix="/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg_build" \
    --pkg-config-flags="--static" \
    --extra-cflags="-I/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg_build/include" \
    --extra-ldflags="-L/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg_build/lib" \
    --extra-libs=-lpthread \
    --extra-libs=-lm \
    --enable-libxcb \
    --bindir="/ffmpeg_sources/bin" && \
    make && \
    make install

# Final image with code and dependencies
FROM lambda-base 

# Copy FFMpeg binary
COPY --from=ffmpeg /ffmpeg_sources/bin/ffmpeg /usr/bin/
```

Comment: sorry @pawel kam , I am not with docker background, but where should I put the lines related to installing the reqs and the cmd in this file sample?

Comment: You can install your requirements before building *ffmpeg*. Use this [Dockerfile](https://github.com/aws-samples/serverless-ui-testing-using-selenium/blob/48373bfadbe0514d4d2ce6e17667e572adf2f02f/Dockerfile) for reference.

Comment: I updated the docker file in the post to reflect your suggestion However I still encounter the same problem

Comment: Hmm. What is the error message? Is it timeout? If so, have you tried to increase the timeout time from the default 3 seconds?

Comment: There are no errors. It just stucks at the import. The image works locally, so I assume something wrong with Lambda, not sure what, though

Comment: I'm running out of ideas. Try increasing Memory in Lambda's general configuration.